# MVC6 Taghelper Post Model to Controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am working on an MVC6 application and I would like a button to post the view's model to the controller.  I have the following markup using a taghelper -

```
<a asp-route-area="MyArea" asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction">Save</a>
```

Here is my model declaration in the view -

```
@model MyObject
```

Here is my controller action -

```
public IActionResult MyAction(MyObject mo)
{            
     return new EmptyResult();
}
```

When I click the button,it is properly routed to thecontroller, but the model object is null.
How do I get the entire model to post back to the controller on the button click?

FYI - my goal here is to have multiple buttons on a form that will post the view's model to different mvc controller based on the button clicked.

EDIT - I don't necessarily need it to post to different controller/actions.  I was able to just let the controller decide how to process and that seems to be accomplish what I need.

Comment: if you want to post then you need to use a form and a button or input type = submit and the model properties must correspond to elements inside the form. a link/anchor tag is just going to make a get request with no model submitted, it is not going to post anything, it is just a link

Comment: if you want to make a form that posts to different controller/action using different buttons then you are going to need to add some javascript to the click of the button to change the form action and then submit the form.

Comment: I ended up following the process mentioned here - https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/11/01/performing-multiple-actions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the solution outlined [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/11/01/performing-multiple-actions.aspx).
Essentially the way it works is that you create two buttons with different names and have controller take parameter with the button names.  Then I just check those parameters and if they have a value, I process in that manner.

Comment: You mentioned that you wanted to post the ViewModel to *different* mvc controller based on the button click. The article you've mentioned posts the ViewModel to the *same* ActionResult of the *same* Controller. Then, inside that ActionResult, you have logic that checks which button was clicked. Is that what you really want? Otherwise as @Joe Audette mentioned, changing the *action* attribute of the form tag is the way to go.

Comment: I actually have to perform different processing based on the click.  I was originally going to accomplish this with different controllers/actions, but now I can just call into one controller and perform the work I needed.  I also could have just had my single controller action redirect to the required controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html form action on a button

something like :

```
<form action="/submitNormal" method="get">
   First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
   Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
   <button type="submit">Submit normal</button><br>
   <button type="submit" formaction="="/submitDifferent">Submit different</button>
</form>
```

not sure about browser support.

Comment: That will work for a get action, but I need to perform a post.

Comment: Change method to "post"